# Suggestion for separating PHP from SQL

Tags: php, class, pdo, repository

I've been struggling with this question for hours.
How to seperate my Mysql calls from my PHP code.
I built a social network using PDO for Mysql queries but the SQL is inside
each class. For example, I have a class `Users` and a method is get all users

```
public function fetchUsers() {
    $Database = new Database();
    $Database->setConnection();
    $dbh = $Database->connect()->getHandle();

    $sql = '<query>';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result) {
        return array('success' => true,     
            'data' => $result);
    }

    return array('success' => false,
        'data' => null);
}
```

Then I have another 10 methods in that class that instantiate the database class and query for results. I hate that. I think my classes should manipulate the data or perform other functions, it just gets messy. I looked into the PDO wrapper class but I still want to seperate the Mysql from the classes. The only route I can see is to put them into a repository. So I could have

```
class Users {
  getUsers() {
      $repo = new UserRepository();
      $repo->findAll();
  }
}
```

However, this feels unnecessary as now I am instantiating 2 classes when I could stick with the original single class that makes the call, why create 2 objects? I know its about readability, but does anyone have another suggestion on how to cleanly seperate the Mysql from my classes?

Comment: Readability and organization are key. Your resistance to "instantiating 2 classes" is misplaced. Go with simple structure, easy to understand, easy to debug. Wins in the long run every time. Memory is cheap - and anyway the overhead of a second class is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: I do like your answer. I know I think too much about the small things, but I figure in the larger scheme they may become an issue. Memory is cheap now a days do I think I will go the repo route.

Comment: I can't get the meaning you put into "separate Mysql from classes" but usually it referred to some ORM-like approach. You may like to take a look at Doctrine ORM or some PHP framework each of them has it's own ORM or AR implementation. Yii and LAraval are most popular

Comment: I used Doctrine in the past, it was a learning curve. It has to be custom per request, but I guess I was trying to imitate something along those lines.